# Tkinter video player library works fine as script but has issue when converted into an exe. (Failed to execute script due to unhandled exception)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

I wrote a python program that uses the library tkVideoPlayer (and others). The python script runs fine without any errors but when I use pyinstaller to convert it into an exe, the exe doesn't run at all and I get the following error. (see image)

Things I have tried already:

- Locating the file and moving it to the folder my exe is in.
- Using a star import for the library
- Using the --hidden option when creating the exe and specifying av/av.libs

[image: Error message when attempting to run the exe.]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of errors. Instead, copy, paste, and format the error text directly in the question. The visually impaired may not be able to see the screenshot.

Comment: create an [mre]

Comment: I can't do that, my exe opens and closes inside of 2 seconds.  I have to be really fast and used print screen

Comment: Use the sample code from here, https://pypi.org/project/tkvideoplayer/
Take this code, and make it into an exe program. It should reproduce the error. (remember to specify the mp4 file)

Comment: create an [mre]  how do you expect someone to help when you haven't provided any information.

Comment: The file wasn't found: av.libs. I assume you didn't set the right path for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue occurred due to me using Anaconda 3 (Sypder). It was using a virtual Environment and pyinstaller failed to locate the library correctly.

Solution: Installed python 3 directly onto windows, then installed pyinstaller and and all the libraries I used. Since that isn't a virtual environment it worked fine and the exe ran perfectly.